# Obtain values based on condition of another column

Tags: r

```
case_number <- c("1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4")
action <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A2")
date <- as.Date(c('2008-11-1','2009-3-25','2010-3-14',"2010-10-14","2010-11-14", '2015-3-14', '2015-4-15', '2016-09-01', '2016-01-01'))

data <- data.frame(case_number,action, date)
```

I am having issues figuring out how to extract unique `case_numbers` for any `action` of `A1` and `A2` occuring right next to each other sorted by date. So for this example it would be only 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to check whether the `lead` values in 'action' are 'A2' and the current row value is 'A1' to `filter` those rows and then `pull` the `case_number` and if need use `distinct` (before the `pull`) or `unique` after that

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   filter(action == "A1" & lead(action == "A2")) %>% 
   pull(case_number)
#[1] 1 2
#Levels: 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How would I modify the code so that it only picks up the ones with A1, A2, A3 together (in that order)? So it would only be case_number 2 for this one.

case_number <- c("1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4")
action <- c("A1", "A2", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A2")
date <- as.Date(c('2008-11-1','2009-3-25','2010-3-14',"2010-10-14","2010-11-14", '2015-3-14', '2015-4-15', '2016-09-01', '2016-01-01'))

data <- data.frame(case_number,action, date)

Comment: @Yingcong  You can specify the `n=2` in second `lead` i.e. `data %>% filter(action == "A1" & lead(action == "A2") & lead(action == "A3", n = 2)) %>% pull(case_number)
[1] 2`